# How to replace regular expression with a calculation

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently working on a calculator, and the method it uses to work out the problems is by performing regular expressions on the input to find operations(e.g addition, subtraction, multiplication, etc.) accordingly with the order of operations, preforms the operation, and then replaces the operation with its result so that can be used with the other operations in the loop. I am having trouble programming the third step.

The relevant code snippet is below:

```py
multiplication_search = re.search(r"\d* \* \d*", calculation)

for other operations to work on
if multiplication_search:
  for result in multiplication_search:
    def mult_terms(equation):
      terms = result.split(" ")
      factor_1 = terms[0]
      factor_2 = terms[2]
      product = str(float(factor_1) * float(factor_2))
      return product
```

*Does anyone have an idea of how I would implement the last step?*

Comment: you should probably ```eval()``` input after some sanitizing and let python do that for you.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have gotten a working prototype with decent sanitizing! I'm starting to make another calculator in C, do you have any tips?

Comment: sorry I don't code in C.